# Text fields with value containing chr(10) show only a first line in Xpages

Tags: xpages

I have an existing app where there are some fields that contain chr(10) in the text as a new line separator. Now I just found that JAVA api (and Xpages controls) can't read the complete text from these fields and always cut the string up to first chr(10) . Can't figure out how to get full text from the fields. Anyone solved this already?

In my app the field value is created using Lotus Script e.g.

```
doc.field=doc.field(0) & Chr(10) & "text" .
```

Now in xpages (and using java api by `doc.getItemValueString("field"))` I'm getting back only text until the first chr(10) value ..

Comment: A code example would be nice =)

Comment: In my app the field value is created using Lotus Script e.g. doc.field=doc.field(0) & Chr(10) & "text" . Now in xpages (and using java api by doc.getItemValueString("field")) I'm getting back only text until the first chr(10) value ...

Comment: Use getItemValue not getItemValueString.

Comment: Tried and doesnt work. I even used computed text on my xpage but it doesnt show whole value. I created textarea field on xpage but also doesnt show entire value ..

Comment: 1. Use `doc.getValue("field")` not `getItemValue` or `getItemValueString`. 2. What's the use case for this data? Knowing what you want to do with it -- from a user perspective -- once you have the correct value might aid in providing the most ideal recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm - just gave it a quick try, but I can't confirm this, so maybe it's not really / only a Chr(10) that's causing trouble here?

Anyways, what you could try is a custom converter for the fields in question. Simply enter code like this for the computed "getAsString" property:

```
value.split(String.fromCharCode(10)).join(" - ");
```

Or use any other (legal) character for the final join.

In case you need to re-convert the input back to something else put the according code into "getAsObject", or otherwise pass the value itself back.

Works nicely for me.

Comment: Tried but no way. I even put print(value) into convertor getAsString at the beginning but can see only a first part of the entire text :-( I looked into former text but its really only chr(10)

Comment: Very strange; to test this I wrote some LS button code in my form putting this into the field: "Line 1" & Chr$(10) & "Line 2". After saving a doc with that I can see via doc properties that the field contains both string lines split by a line break. Rendering that field through an Xpage Edit box the result is a single line of string like that: - "Line 1Line 2", so the line break is simply omitted. - Maybe write some code that analyzes the entire field content and returning the ascii code for each character. Maybe besides the Chr(10) there's some other strange something in there

Comment: In properties box on LN client a can see entire value. But to be more specific the code is a bit strange(its not mine, its app from our customer) because the value is appended to single value field by  NotesItem method like this: Call item.AppendToTextList(oldtxt & Chr(10) & sttxt )

Comment: ok that's a different thing then: a real Notes text list with line feeds in at least one of the list elements! - In that case you should also try the edit box's "multipleSeparator" property and see what happens then. Also check whether the Notes fields contain a text list as opposed to plain text

Comment: In property box its single value text string, the former developer just used AppendToTextList to put value into the field.

Comment: Hmm - dunno. Just tried to apply a similar code as you app has it, but I still can't get this to "break": with or without my converter code the entire field content shows up inside the edit box. - As I recommended above: write some ascii character anylyzer and check what's in the field

Comment: Change " - " to "\n".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if hitting enter in a text field in the notes client creates a chr(10) but give this converter a try:

```
<xp:this.converter>
    <xp:customConverter>
        <xp:this.getAsObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Explode(value,"\n");}]]></xp:this.getAsObject>
        <xp:this.getAsString><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Implode(value,"\n");}]]></xp:this.getAsString>
    </xp:customConverter>
</xp:this.converter>
```